# How to get the IP address of the docker compose

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get ip address with docker compose by jenkinsfile.

My Jenkinsfile run the docker-compose, next run service which should be run with java args (np. `-Dapp.url=http://(ip address of the docker):8080/app`).

Can i get ip address with docker compose in jenkinsfile?

Comment: it accepts `-Dapp.url=http://0.0.0.0:8080/app` as well, right?

Comment: try use docker-inspect to get the ip address, why don't you use the domain name instead of IP?